2/3 cats fighting, help/advice urgently needed and greatly appreciated
I have 3 cats and I have issues with two of them getting along. My first cat is the oldest and we adopted him in 2015, he is laid back and lazy and doesn’t fight with the new cat but doesn’t bother getting to know her (so neutral). My second cat I got in 2019 and gets along very well with cat 1. My third cat I got this October and she is very skittish. She was a stray and is a tortoise/calico cat (a female while both others are male). She took awhile to get used to us and tends to stay in my bedroom and barley goes downstairs while my two other cats stay in my moms room. Cat 2 tends to chase cat 3 and it seems like cat 3 is scared of her (and of cat 1 but a normal amount/barley). Cat 2 will often wait at the other end of the hallway to wait for cat 3 to peak out of my room at the other end of the hallway. If she is in the hallway she will often be chased by him into mine. Sometimes swatting and hissing happens between them both to.
My door does not close so it’s usually a tiny bit ajar, and sometimes they both have stare downs with cat 3 in my room and the other in the hallway. Sometimes hissing and rarely swatting happens.
I am very stressed about them not getting along and worried. I am not sure what I can do. It seems like cat 2 wants to be friends with cat 3 but doesn’t know how exactly, and cat 3 has gained a fear of him so if he does come close she will run away, hiss or rarely swat. I want to do anything I can to get them to get along but I’m not sure what to do. I would try holding one while the other is in the room but cat 3 is still skiddish so I cannot pick her up or stand/walk near her if I tried.
FYI cat 1 is 10, cat 2 is 5-7 and cat 3 is 2

Have you followed any specific process to introduce your new cat when you got her? Are your cats neutered / spayed? To me it sounds like cat 2 doesn't accept cat 3 as a new family member at all and instead sees her as an intruder who must be chased away. The trouble maker here is cat 2, not cat 3 btw.

Hi! My cat 3 stayed in a separate room for a few weeks, since she stayed under the bed so long. Cat 2 was curious and would stick her paws under. We opened the door but she stayed in that room on the bed, and if I put cat 2 on the bed they would be comfortable and sit a little away for the most part, I’m not really sure when the chasing started but the fighting came after them sort of getting along. Idk why they stopped getting along. All are neutered. Cat 2 is very friendly normally, and I truly think his intentions started out friendly but I’m not sure what happend ☹️

I do really want to believe part of cat 2 wanted/wants to be friends and this is some sort of way he thinks is playing, but since cat 3 doesn’t view it as that it started more fear and hissing (cat 3 being a stray also prob contributed to this, she would hiss and swat to me before but now is comfortable and does not, she is very friendly) out of fear which caused the downfall (this is not me blaming cat 3 since it is cat 2 now instigating, sorry I’m bad with my words and that I gave a really long response )
